# A map to show how bitcoin has been implemented

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I'd like to understand how Bitcoin has been implemented.

I'm  aware of this page[1] and also, I know how Bitcoin works in theory.

But I'd like to know if there's any map/documentation, that allows me to figure out (in bitcoin implementation) which function is called one after another and how different components fit together.

[1].https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. Have you tried starting here?
https://bitcoin.org/en/how-it-works

Otherwise you should elaborate on which component or process you are trying to figure out. Bitcoin consists of many pieces, including the blockchain, transactions, miners, wallets, and full clients who route traffic around the network.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the "not-really-specific" answer but your question is pretty broad too.

Here you can find all the documentation regarding BitCoin -> [Bitcoin Developer Documentation](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-documentation)